# What properties of music does MPmediaquery see?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to figure out whether there is a way to check if a user legally purchased individual music tracks. Please help! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Checking DRM is currently not supported using `MPMediaQuery`. See the [`MPMediaItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/General_Media_Item_Property_Keys) documentation - media item property keys.

In addition, checking the file's origin is also not possible. To conclude, checking if media was legally purchased is impossible.